# Issue while parsing JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

I need to parse JSON value. I can get 'name' value but I am unable to retrieve json value if the property has colon(:).
PFB the code

```
<script>
var text = '{"name": "james","age": "30","re:moto" : "Hi"}'

var obj = JSON.parse(text);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.name + "<br>" + obj.age ;
</script>
```

Here I am getting name value as 'james'. Giving error while retrieving 're:moto'. 
Can any one tell me how to retrieve property if it has colon?

Answer (score 5):

You would need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

```js
var text = '{"name": "james","age": "30","re:moto" : "Hi"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(obj["re:moto"]);
```

Comment: I have one question. I knew the json object name. But i dont know what property/field it has. Assume that 'abc' json object. I just want to know all the fields it has. Is there any method to list all the fields?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys